# Get an Error that .filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried to create an autocomplete suggestion box from an Thailand's province database URL.

This is my source code. I export this to App.js in src directory

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
  const [singleProvince, setSingleProvince] = useState([]);
  const [singleProvinceData, setSingleProvinceData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

  const province_dataBase_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/earthchie/jquery.Thailand.js/master/jquery.Thailand.js/database/raw_database/raw_database.json'

  useEffect(() => {  
  const promises = new Array(20).fill(fetch(province_dataBase_url)
  .then((res) => { 
    return res.json().then((data) => { 
      const createSingleProvince = data.filter( (each) => {
        if (false == (singleProvince.includes(each.province))) {
          setSingleProvince(singleProvince.push(each.province))
          setSingleProvinceData(singleProvinceData.push(each))

        }
      })
      return data;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }) 
  }))
  }, [])

  
  useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      };
  });

  const handleClickOutside = event => {
      const { current: wrap } = wrapperRef;
      if (wrap && !wrap.contains(event.target)) {
        setDisplay(false);
      }
  };

  const updateProvince = inputProvince => {
      setSearch(inputProvince);
      setDisplay(false);
  };
  
  return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef} className="flex-container flex-column pos-rel">
      <input
        id="auto"
        onClick={() => setDisplay(!display)}
        placeholder="Type to search"
        value={search}
        onChange={event => setSearch(event.target.value)}
      />
      {display && (
        <div className="autoContainer">
          { singleProvinceData
            .filter( ({province}) => province.indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1)
            .map( (each,i) => {
              return (
                <div 
                  onClick={() => updateProvince(each.province)}
                  className="singleProvinceData"
                  key={i}
                  tabIndex="0"
                >
                <span>{each.province}</span>
                </div>
              )
            })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test
```

When click on an input box, the console says "TypeError: singleProvinceData.filter is not a function"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Dzq.png)

I cannot find out what's wrong with my code

Comment: why do you write pure function in interpolation {} syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the "singleProvinceData" state is not set correctly.
you cannot push data directly into the state.

```
   useEffect(() => {  
      const promises = new Array(20).fill(fetch(province_dataBase_url)
      .then((res) => { 
        return res.json().then((data) => { 

          const shallowSingleProvinceList = [];
          const shallowSingleProvinceDataList = [];
          const createSingleProvince = data.filter( (each) => {
            if (false == (singleProvince.includes(each.province))) {
              shallowSingleProvinceList.push(each.province)
              shallowSingleProvinceDataList.push(each)
            }
          })

          setSingleProvince(shallowSingleProvinceList)
          setSingleProvinceData(shallowSingleProvinceDataList)
          
          return data;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }) 
      }))
      }, [])
```

You can show the data conditionally

```
 {display && (
        <div className="autoContainer">
          { singleProvinceData && singleProvinceData
            .filter( ({province}) => province.indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1)
            .map( (each,i) => {
              return (
                <div 
                  onClick={() => updateProvince(each.province)}
                  className="singleProvinceData"
                  key={i}
                  tabIndex="0"
                >
                <span>{each.province}</span>
                </div>
              )
            })}
        </div>
      )}
```